# Proving some two sequences is going to $0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ be two sequences of a real numbers. If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} = 0$, then prove  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} \sin(b_{n}) = 0 $$

$|\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} \sin(b_{n})  - 0|  <= \epsilon$

un.. its kind of obvious $\sin(b_{n})$ is alternating and bounded

and finite * 0 = 0 .. but I'm not sure how to put this nicely

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/if-b-n-is-a-bounded-sequence-and-lim-a-n-0-show-that-lima-nb-n-0

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the squeeze theorem?

For any $n$,
$$
0 \le |a_n \sin b_n| = |a_n||\sin b_n| \le |a_n| \cdot 1 = |a_n|
$$
$$
0 \le |a_n \sin b_n| \le |a_n|
$$

Now what happens do this inequality when you take the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Neat, simple and short. +1