# if $b_{n}$ is bounded and $\lim a_{n}=0$, show that $\lim a_{n}b_{n}=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Please check my proof

we have $lim a_{n}=0$

then $|a_{n}-0|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$

Suppose $lim b_{n}=L$

$b_{n}-L|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$

then $ lim a_{n}b_{n}$

$|a_{n}b_{n}+a_{n}L-0|=|a_{n}b_{n}+a_{n}L =|a_{n}||b_{n}+L|<\sqrt{\epsilon }\sqrt{\epsilon }=\epsilon $

Comment: Why $b_n$ is convergent?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/if-b-n-is-a-bounded-sequence-and-lim-a-n-0-show-that-lima-nb-n-0?rq=1

Comment: $b_n$ is bounded that doesn't mean it is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $|b_na_n|\leq M|a_n|$ for all $n$ and for some $M$,what does the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) says?